# git 2018: Is there a way to rename a branch at remote for all users?

Tags: git

I understand that branch-renaming is essentially just deleting the old branch and re-creating a new one.

Is there a feature by now that allows this process to propagate to all users, i.e. using some guid instead of branch name?

For example, if another person have a tracking branch to origin/a and I renamed that to origin/b, I'm hoping there's a feature where his tracking branch will automatically become origin/b on the next fetch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand that branch-renaming is essentially just deleting the old branch and re-creating a new one.

Maybe, or maybe not.  If you use `git branch -m` to rename a branch in your own repository, the reflog for the old name becomes the reflog for the new name; if you use `git branch newname oldname && git branch -D oldname` to create a new name pointing to the same commit, then delete the old name, the reflog goes away.  So that would imply that the answer is "not"—but see below.

> Is there a feature by now that allows this process to propagate to all users, i.e. using some guid instead of branch name?

Your branch names are *independent of* my branch names, and vice versa, so, **definitely not**.  Even if I have your repository set as a remote such as `origin`, my `master` is not your `master`.  My `master` is quite independent of your `master`.  I remember your `master` via my `origin/master`.

> For example, if another person have a tracking branch to origin/a and I renamed that to origin/b, I'm hoping there's a feature where his tracking branch will automatically become origin/b on the next fetch.

While that might be a nice feature, it does not exist.  When I `git fetch origin`, I *add* your `b` to my collection of `origin/*` names.  If I have not selected the `--prune` option, I retain my `origin/a` copy of your `a` from earlier.  If I *have* selected the `--prune` option, I have my Git automatically delete my `origin/a` (and its reflog!).  So, were it not for all this branch-becomes-remote-tracking-name-that-is-different stuff going on, that would imply that renaming a branch really *is* equivalent to first creating a new name, then deleting the old one.  (The order is important since otherwise the commits might be garbage collected between the two operations.)

Meanwhile, if I have a branch named `didgeridoo` that has `origin/a` set as its upstream, my `didgeridoo` continues to have `origin/a` set as its upstream, *even if I have selected the `--prune` option and I no longer have an `origin/a`*.

In any case, the fundamental guiding principle here is that *each user has his or her own branch names* and any changes to any remote *never* affect them.  (For `--mirror` clones, this particular principle goes out the window entirely, but mirrors are normally bare and have no work done in them.)